# How to get or create object in another model while updating some model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a select2 option to select the reporters in my form. User randomly puts the reporters name in the news create form and while saving the form it also creates the reporter objects and assign these objects in News reporters(many to many ) field. This works fine while creating the objects

While updating it got some issues.In the update form there will be the reporters which are already assigned in the news.And user can add reporters and also can remove the reporters from the form. Here if user add the new reporter in the form then I want to create reporter object and assign the reporter object in many to many field and so if the user removes some reporter.
But this code creates reporter object even if it is already created and assigned in the News object.

*I want to check if the reporter is already in the News then i don't want to create object in the Reporter model .If only user add new reporter then I want to create reporter object in Reporter model and then assign this object in News. How can I do it ?*

```
class UpdateNews(View):
    template_name = 'update_news.html'
    categories = NewsCategory.objects.order_by('-created')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        news = get_object_or_404(News, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        form = CreateNewsForm(instance=news)
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'form': form, 'news': news, 'categories': self.categories})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        target = get_object_or_404(News, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        form = CreateNewsForm(request.POST, instance=news)
        if form.is_valid():
            news = form.save()
            reporters = request.POST.getlist('reporters')
            reporters_pk = [Reporter.objects.create(name=reporter).pk for reporter in reporters]
            news.reporters.set(reporters_pk)
            return redirect('list_news')
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'form': form, 'news': news, 'categories': self.categories})
```

models

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reporters = models.ManyToManyField(Reporter, related_name='reporters')
```

I had tried using the `get_or_create` method but it throws an error

```
reporters_pk = [Reporter.objects.get_or_create(name=reporter).pk for reporter in reporters]
```

Error

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple back

```
instance, created = get_or_create(...)
```

if you would like to access reporter's pk, try to get the instance first

```
reporters_pk = [Reporter.objects.get_or_create(name=reporter)[0].pk for reporter in reporters]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best approach would be to use Django's built-in `get_or_create` method. In your case this would give:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        target = get_object_or_404(News, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        form = CreateNewsForm(request.POST, instance=news)
        if form.is_valid():
            news = form.save()            
            reporters = request.POST.getlist('reporters')
            # magic here 'get_or_create'
            reporters_pk = [Reporter.objects.get_or_create(name=reporter).pk for reporter in reporters]
            news.reporters.set(reporters_pk)
            return redirect('list_news')
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'form': form, 'news': news, 'categories': self.categories})
```

so for eeach reporter which returns `True` for the identifier `name=reporter` it fetches the existing object from the database, otherwise it creates a new one. That way you avoid ending up with multiple entries.

So basically you already pointed in the right direction with your headline or you didn't describe your issue properly ;)

Comment: I had tried this it throws an error.`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pk'`